# How can I get ACS API keys using Appcelerator Studio?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, push, appcelerator

I have to configure push notifications on an Android (and iOS but it's done) app. The notifications will work via my company server. The server is already configured :

```
// google cloud messages 
'gcm' => [ 
    'key' => 'SERVER KEY'
```

But in the tiapp.xml file in Appcelerator, I do not know which key has to go where :

```
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">WHICH KEY?</property>
<property name="acs-api-key" type="string">WHICH KEY?</property>
```

In Google developer console I can see 3 keys :

- Android key
- Browser key
- Server key (used in the company server config file)

I tried all these keys but the notifications won't work. Sender ID is correctly set in the config.json file.

Do you have any idea where the issue comes from ?

Comment: `acs` keys are only needed if you send notifications through Arrow. These keys are for arrow ;)

Comment: Look at the `Ti.Goosh` module to get your notifications to work https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh

Comment: Actually I'm using the module ct.timeko.gcm (made by the app devs) : https://github.com/a-voityuk/CTTimekoGCM

I'm new in this environment, and I don't know what to do with all these keys.

Comment: also good. But you don't need ACS keys if you don't use Arrow

Comment: Thanks Rene :)

Notifications still don't work, I don't know where the problem comes from. I have this "Android key" in Google console, which I don't know where to put.